# what are Non-AI methods in detecting how much brown pixels an image have

Tags: python, data-cleaning, image-preprocessing

looking for a non-AI approach on how to find how much "brown" color a 256x256 px image have. I am making a dataset that will be used as training data for AI later on. There are several thousand pictures that i need to sort into several classification. Doing this manually will literally take days. So im planning on making a rough sorting algorithm that will categorize the image into their general categories, and will be fine tuned later on by actual humans. Theoretically saving upto 70% man hours.

To be categorized into their general categories i would need to know how many pixel at a given intensity the image have, e.g. 5% of the pixels are dark-brown 20% are lightish brown. Basically a color histogram for the color brown, but since a brown is not a primary color, i have to mask it first to black and white and do the histogram in black and white

[image]
[image]

[image]

Here we can see that there are a lot of pixels in the middle portion of the histogram so i can then place it in its appropriate category.

Downside to this method is i really have to tune the color value of "brown" so that the mask works on every image. Was wondering if there are alternative methods i can use to detect how much brown an image have.